# Log/Detect Clipboard access

Tags: linux, macos, clipboard

With the public beta access to iOS 14 people got a warning when apps access the clipboard, and it lead to people realizing that many apps just grab everything from the clipboard they can get and send it back to their servers. Amongst other things this led to widespread criticism of the TikTok App.

Is there a way to monitor access to the clipboard on Mac and Linux systems e.g. Ubuntu? Just in order to get a feeling on how "liberal" programmers of non mobile systems are with clipboard access?

Comment: It's possible but complicated. It's also pointless on its own: these applications can access all your files. Accessing the clipboard wouldn't be particularly useful.

Comment: at least some password managers in Linux use the clipboard (I know keepassXC does, if you did not enable browser integration).  That's a high value item that is not available simply from reading the files (at least not trivially).

Comment: Complicated or not, this would be a very interesting tool/functionality to have available. Any idea where should we look to get this information?